# Animate the Presentation of AdMob Interstitial in iOS

Tags: ios, animation, admob, interstitial

I'm evaluating the possibility of including AdMob interstitial into my iOS app. One thing I'm not sure is whether we can present the interstitial in an animated way. From the document, it looks like the only way we can display the interstitial is to use the

```
presentFromRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController
```

method since GADInterstitial is not a view but an NSObject. Is there any way we can display it in an animation such as sliding/scrolling in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the delegate function, use this to display interstitial ad with animation:

```
- (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial
{
    [interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
}
```